# Puzzling MediaCodec.BufferInfo.size values

Tags: android-mediacodec

I use MediaCodec to decode H.264/H.265 video streams. I don't think the code of thousands of lines is relevant to my question, so please allow me to avoid pasting the code here. Let me emphasize that the decoding works flawlessly. I am asking this question primarily out of curiosity, not for solving a problem.

```
MediaCodec.BufferInfo bi = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
...
int iOutputBufferIndex = myMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bi, TIMEOUT_USEC);
logd("debug", "Output buffer size: " + bi.size);
```

[The official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.BufferInfo#size) says that MediaCodec.BufferInfo.size is "The amount of data (in bytes) in the buffer." I have tested three video streams decoded by the code. MediaCodec.BufferInfo.size is 1 for an H.265 video and 8 for two H.264 video streams. These numbers do not look like "The amount of data (in bytes) in the buffer.". My understanding is that the buffer has decoded video frame.

Could anyone shed some light on this (i.e. the exact meaning of MediaCodec.BufferInfo.size) ?

Comment: I'm having trouble decoding frames. My buffer size is 8 (As you've indicated in your question), frameAvailable is never triggered.